# Llamar getActionCommand con un KeyEvent

Tags: java, mvc, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo una clase GUI y otra clase Manejadora de eventos que implementa los Listeners. En la GUI tengo 2 botones que tienen como escucha a la clase controladora.

¿Cómo hago para que el método keyPressed de la clase manejadora identifique cual JButton se pulso? Es que en el método actionPerformed lo hago con getActionCommand y setActionCommand en cada boton del GUI, pero solo funciona con clicks del mouse, sin embargo no sé como es con eventos del teclado.

Saludos.

Comment: El método que buscas para los botones entre otros es este `setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_TuTecla);`   También deberías editar la pregunta y añadir parte de tu código para poder ayudarte en condiciones.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer para identificar que tecla se pulsa es un switch donde comparas el codigo de la tecla de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                System.out.println("flecha de arriba");
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                System.out.println("flecha de abajo");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                System.out.println("flecha de la derecha");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                System.out.println("flecha de la izquierda");
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
                    break;
        }
    }
```

este es un ejemplo con el código de las flechas del teclado, si deseas obtener el de una letra puedes cambiar los casos por uno asi

```
case KeyEvent.VK_C
```

este es el caso de la letra C por ejemplo,
para hacer todo esto debes implementar la interface keylistener